# Typecasting derived object to base object with generics

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, casting

I have a covariant/contravariant issue with generics.
Here's a code of what I'm trying to do :

in framework DLL:

```
namespace framework {
    public interface IBase 
    {
        //Some code...
    }

    public abstract class AOverClass<T> : IBase where T : IBase
    {
        public AOverClass(T pObject)
        {
            //Some code
        }
        //Some code...
    }

    public class workerClass 
    {
        public Dictionary<Type, Type> ObjDictionary;
        public AOverClass<IBase> GetOverObj(IBase initObj){

            // Get the over Obj type from a dictionary that was loaded previously
            // the dictionary contains KVP of <Type, Type> then using Reflection 
            // to initialise a new OverObj

            Type t = Dictionary[initObj.GetType()];
            Type[] _typesParamsConstructor = new Type[1];
            _typesParamsConstructor[0] = initObj.GetType();
            Object[] _valParamsConstructor = new Object[1];
            _valParamsConstructor [0] = initObj;

            // BIG ISSUE HERE

            return (AOverClass<IBase>)t.GetConstructor(_typesParamsConstructor).Invoke(_valParamsConstructor);
        }
    }
}
```

in application that references the framework DLL:

```
namespace myApp {
    public class Param : framework.IBase, myApp.IOtherNeeded
    {
        //Some code
    }

    public class OverParam : framework.AOverClass<Param>
    {
        public OverParam(Param pObject) :base(pObject)
        {
            //Some code...
        }
    }

    public class App
    {
        private framework.workerClass _wc;
        public void Init()
        {
            _wc = new framework.workerClass();
            _wc.ObjDictionary.Add(typeof(Param), typeof(OverParam));
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            _wc.GetOverObj(new Param());
        }
    }
}
```

The workerClass throws an Exception that it can't cast `OverParam` to `AOverClass<IBase>`.
How can I work round this?

**Foot note :** 
There are no initialisation issues (i.e. the dictionary), I'm just no writting all the code that is not relevent to the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instance of `OverParam` is an `AOverClass<Param>` by definition.

But you are trying to cast that instance of `OverParam` to `AOverClass<IBase>`. That fails.

Now just because any

> `Param` "is" `IBase`

can we or can we not conclude that every

> `AOverClass<Param>` "is" `AOverClass<IBase>`

?

The answer is: That works precisely if `AOverClass<T>` is ***covariant*** in `T`. The only types that can be covariant (marked with `out` before the type parameter `T`) in the current version of C# and .NET, are interface types and delegate types. But `AOverClass<T>` is a ***class type***.

Also, when we look at your class:

```
public abstract class AOverClass<T> : IBase where T : IBase
{
    public AOverClass(T pObject)  // an "in" parameter of type T here! :-(
    {
        //Some code
    }
    //Some code...
}
```

we see that you use `T` contravariantly. So even if the language allowed class types to be covariant, it wouldn't apply in your case. This indicates that there is something fundamentally wrong with your assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for the info... So you're saying that I need to change my abstract class to an interface and then use the constructor parameter as `out`. That way I'll be able to use covariance and acheive my goal? I'll give it a try...